# How biblatex prepares the final references list

Tags: biblatex

I am struggling a bit to figure out how to present the reference as I wish.
Here is an example, this is my `.bib` file

```
author = {Callaghan, David P. and Ahmadi, Afshin and Nielsen, Peter},
doi = {10.1007/s00348-011-1183-2},
isbn = {0034801111832},
issn = {07234864},
journal = {Experiments in Fluids},
number = {6},
pages = {1657--1671},
title = {{Transient wave behaviour over an underwater sliding hump from experiments and analytical and numerical modelling}},
volume = {51},
year = {2011}
}
```

This is how it appears on the report itself
[image]

and how it appears on the reference list
[image]

however, what I really want

1. In the report, I want the cite to just show the first author like

> Callaghan etc 2011.

2. In the reference list, I want it arranged this way

> Callaghan, David P., Ahmadi Afshin , and  Nielsen Peter(2011). “Transient wave behaviour over
>   an underwater sliding hump from experiments and analytical and numerical modelling”. In:
>   Experiments in Fluids 51.6, pp. 1657–1671.

All authors should be sorted as last name, first name.  (Actually, only the first author is sorted that way.)

Below is my biblatex entry

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
citestyle=authoryear, 
style=authoryear-ibid,  
uniquename=false,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false
]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = Blue
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{MyCollection.bib}
```

Is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You want the options

```
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=1,
maxbibnames=999,
```

and then

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

Note finally that in

```
citestyle=authoryear, 
style=authoryear-ibid,
```

the `citestyle` specification is superfluous, it is overridden by `style=authoryear-ibid`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Don't you mind me asking another question?
I have some references with curly brackets there, I am not sure how to get rid of, a example like

 Sobey, R. J. and Liang, H.-B. (1987). “Complex Envelope Identification of Wave Groups”. In:
Coastal Engineering 1986. American Society of Civil Engineers ({ASCE}).

The ASCE with curly brackets I want get rid of.

Comment: @ZhifangHu That is a new question. Please ask a new question about that with a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and the example bib entry.